# Select different people with the same name in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the structure like:

```
name      date      company
Alice   19-01-01    A Global
Bob     19-01-01    B Corp
'''
Alice   19-03-01    C Global
Bob     19-01-01    D Corp
```

Since `Alice` was in different company at different date. I consider this person the same person who jump from `A Global` to `C Global`. As for `Bob` since there are 2 `Bob` in the same day. I consider they are 2 different people with the same name.

My task is to find all the different people with the same name and change their name to "name - company" like `Bob-B corp`

How can I achieve this in mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this ?

```
UPDATE table SET name = CONCAT(name,"-",company)
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table AS t2 
WHERE t2.name = table.name AND t2.date = table.date AND t2.company <> table.company
GROUP BY name,date HAVING COUNT(company) > 1)
```